Can socks5 proxies work similiar to http connect?
I have difficulties understanding socks5 proxies.
I would like to know if I can avoid socks5 proxies to see the traffic between the client and destination. I would like to achieve something similiar to http connect where the client and the destination server communicate directly and the proxy simply forwards data without inspecting or modifying the data.
Is it sufficient to connect to an https site to ensure that the socks5 proxy cannot see the content I exchange with the site?

A http proxy can "see" the content without any problems if you use CONNECT. The only way to prevent a proxy to see the data is using https connections to the target servers. Then it doesn't matter if it is a http or a socks proxy.
